# Shibboleth SP - Signing and Encryption Key

Tags: encryption, shibboleth

I have a Shibboleth SP installed on Server 2012 R2. I tried to submit the metadata to be imported into the IDP and was told that without having the signing or encryption key, they won't be able to send the SP any assertions.

From what I've found on this, Shibboleth SP has the key to use included in the default installation. I believe that is the sp-cert.pem and the sp-key.pem included in the C:\opt\shibboleth-sp\etc\shibboleth folder.

I'm not sure how to reference it in the Shibboleth2.xml file either.
Here is my shibboleth2.xml as of right now:

```
<SPConfig xmlns="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:native:sp:config"
xmlns:conf="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:native:sp:config"
xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"    
xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"
logger="syslog.logger" clockSkew="180">

<!-- The OutOfProcess section contains properties affecting the shibd daemon. -->
<OutOfProcess logger="shibd.logger">

</OutOfProcess>

<!-- The InProcess section conrains settings affecting web server modules/filters. -->
<InProcess logger="native.logger">
    <ISAPI normalizeRequest="true">

        <Site id="1" name="sp-example.com"/>
    </ISAPI>
</InProcess>


<!-- This set of components stores sessions and other persistent data in daemon memory. -->
<StorageService type="Memory" id="mem" cleanupInterval="900"/>
<SessionCache type="StorageService" StorageService="mem" cacheTimeout="3600" inprocTimeout="900" cleanupInterval="900"/>
<ReplayCache StorageService="mem"/>
<ArtifactMap artifactTTL="180"/>



<!-- To customize behavior, map hostnames and path components to applicationId and other settings. -->
<RequestMapper type="Native">
    <RequestMap applicationId="default">
        <Host name="sp-example.com" authType="shibboleth" requireSession="true"/>

    </RequestMap>
</RequestMapper>


<ApplicationDefaults id="default" policyId="default"
    entityID="urn:mace:university.edu:shibboleth:test:sp:university:administrative:cscn:sp-example.com"
    homeURL="https://sp-example.com"
    REMOTE_USER="eppn persistent-id targeted-id"
    signing="false" encryption="false"
    >


    <Sessions lifetime="28800" timeout="3600" checkAddress="false"
        handlerURL="/Shibboleth.sso" handlerSSL="true"
        exportLocation="http://sp-example.com/Shibboleth.sso/GetAssertion" exportACL="165.91.23.32"
        idpHistory="false" idpHistoryDays="7" cookieProps="https" >


        <SessionInitiator type="Chaining" Location="/Login" isDefault="true" id="Intranet"
                relayState="cookie" entityID="urn:mace:university.edu:shibboleth:test:idp:university:administrative:cscn:idp-test.university.edu">
            <SessionInitiator type="SAML2" defaultACSIndex="1" acsByIndex="false" template="bindingTemplate.html"/>
            <SessionInitiator type="Shib1" defaultACSIndex="5"/>
        </SessionInitiator>

        <md:AssertionConsumerService Location="/SAML2/POST" index="1"
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"/>
        <md:AssertionConsumerService Location="/SAML2/POST-SimpleSign" index="2"
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST-SimpleSign"/>
        <md:AssertionConsumerService Location="/SAML2/Artifact" index="3"
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact"/>
        <md:AssertionConsumerService Location="/SAML2/ECP" index="4"
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:PAOS"/>
        <md:AssertionConsumerService Location="/SAML/POST" index="5"
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:profiles:browser-post"/>
        <md:AssertionConsumerService Location="/SAML/Artifact" index="6"
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:profiles:artifact-01"/>

        <!-- LogoutInitiators enable SP-initiated local or global/single logout of sessions. -->
        <LogoutInitiator type="Chaining" Location="/Logout" relayState="cookie">
            <LogoutInitiator type="SAML2" template="bindingTemplate.html"/>
            <LogoutInitiator type="Local"/>
        </LogoutInitiator>

        <!-- md:SingleLogoutService locations handle single logout (SLO) protocol messages. -->
        <md:SingleLogoutService Location="/SLO/SOAP"
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP"/>
        <md:SingleLogoutService Location="/SLO/Redirect" conf:template="bindingTemplate.html"
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"/>
        <md:SingleLogoutService Location="/SLO/POST" conf:template="bindingTemplate.html"
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"/>
        <md:SingleLogoutService Location="/SLO/Artifact" conf:template="bindingTemplate.html"
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact"/>

        <!-- md:ManageNameIDService locations handle NameID management (NIM) protocol messages. -->
        <md:ManageNameIDService Location="/NIM/SOAP"
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP"/>
        <md:ManageNameIDService Location="/NIM/Redirect" conf:template="bindingTemplate.html"
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"/>
        <md:ManageNameIDService Location="/NIM/POST" conf:template="bindingTemplate.html"
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"/>
        <md:ManageNameIDService Location="/NIM/Artifact" conf:template="bindingTemplate.html"
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact"/>


        <md:ArtifactResolutionService Location="/Artifact/SOAP" index="1"
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP"/>

        <!-- Extension service that generates "approximate" metadata based on SP configuration. -->
        <Handler type="MetadataGenerator" Location="/Metadata" signing="false"/>

        <!-- Status reporting service. -->
        <Handler type="Status" Location="/Status" acl="127.0.0.1"/>

        <!-- Session diagnostic service. -->
        <Handler type="Session" Location="/Session" showAttributeValues="false"/>

    </Sessions>


    <Errors session="sessionError.html"
        metadata="metadataError.html"
        access="accessError.html"
        ssl="sslError.html"
        localLogout="localLogout.html"
        globalLogout="globalLogout.html"
        supportContact="root@localhost"
        logoLocation="/shibboleth-sp/logo.jpg"
        styleSheet="/shibboleth-sp/main.css"/>


    <!-- Chains together all your metadata sources. -->
    <MetadataProvider type="Chaining">
        <!-- Example of remotely supplied batch of signed metadata. -->
        <MetadataProvider type="XML" uri="https://idp-test.university.edu/universityfed-test-metadata-signed.xml"
             backingFilePath="C:\opt\shibboleth-sp\etc\shibboleth\universityfed-test-metadata-signed.xml" reloadInterval="7200">
        </MetadataProvider>
    </MetadataProvider>

    <!-- Chain the two built-in trust engines together. -->
    <TrustEngine type="Chaining">
        <TrustEngine type="ExplicitKey"/>
        <TrustEngine type="PKIX"/>
    </TrustEngine>

    <!-- Map to extract attributes from SAML assertions. -->
    <AttributeExtractor type="XML" path="attribute-map.xml"/>

    <!-- Use a SAML query if no attributes are supplied during SSO. -->
    <AttributeResolver type="Query"/>

    <!-- Default filtering policy for recognized attributes, lets other data pass. -->
    <AttributeFilter type="XML" path="attribute-policy.xml"/>


</ApplicationDefaults>

<!-- Each policy defines a set of rules to use to secure messages. -->
<SecurityPolicies>
    <!-- The predefined policy enforces replay/freshness and permits signing and client TLS. -->
    <Policy id="default" validate="false">
        <Rule type="MessageFlow" checkReplay="true" expires="60"/>
        <Rule type="ClientCertAuth" errorFatal="true"/>
        <Rule type="XMLSigning" errorFatal="true"/>
        <Rule type="SimpleSigning" errorFatal="true"/>
    </Policy>
</SecurityPolicies>
```

According to an email I recieved, I need to include `<md:KeyDescriptor use="encryption">` and `<md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">`

From what I found online, it should be something similar to:

```
<md:SPSSODescriptor>
<md:KeyDescriptor>
    <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509Certificate>
                hash found in sp-cert.pem file
            </ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
</md:KeyDescriptor>
```

I don't know where I should be putting this in the Shibboleth.xml file.

Can anybody help to get me on the right track? I have been through a decent amount of documentation and guides from different institutions, but haven't found any direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to add the following line to the Shibboleth2.xml (in the `ApplicationDefaults` section):

```
<CredentialResolver type="File" key="sp-key.pem" certificate="sp-cert.pem"/>
```

`sp-key.pem` and `sp-cert.pem` are included in the Shibboleth installation.  They are located in the same folder as the `Shibboleth2.xml` file.

I also changed the line:

```
<ApplicationDefaults id="default" policyId="default" entityID="urn:mace:university.edu:shibboleth:test:sp:university:administrative:cscn:sp-example.com"
    homeURL="https://sp-example.com"
    REMOTE_USER="eppn persistent-id targeted-id"
    signing="false" encryption="false"
    >
```

To:

```
<ApplicationDefaults id="default" policyId="default"
 entityID="urn:mace:university.edu:shibboleth:test:sp:university:administrative:cscn:sp-example.com"
    homeURL="https://sp-example.com"
    REMOTE_USER="eppn persistent-id targeted-id"
    signing="true" encryption="true"
    >
```

When the line is added, the Metadata has entries for for the certs and needs to be reimported to the IDP.